# @media (min-width: ) and (max-width: ) query not working Properly

Tags: html, css, responsive

i am using `@media` query to convert my html page to responsive page but i am stuck to convert my page to responsive page.

i am using

```
@media(min-width:480px) and (max-width:959px)
{
   body
   {
       background-color:red;
   }
}
```

in my css Code

but background-color is changing when my browser width is 942px.
and whatever CSS code i am writing for `@media(min-width:480px) and (max-width:959px)`. CSS style is working fine only for (max-width:).

with these bugs/issues i am not able to convert my html page to responsive page.

Comment: Your browser width is within your media query.... that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Specify your question please, because the provided code just works as intended. If width hits 480 px, then background becomes red until width hits 960 px.

Comment: Actually the browser window takes some width for scroll bar.So some pixels are calculated for the width of the scroll bar.The problem is happening due to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use always this code for making responsive

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){

  /*Your style put here*/

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

  /*Your style put here*/

}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){

  /*Your style put here*/

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){

  /*Your style put here*/

}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px){

  /*Your style put here*/

}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){

  /*Your style put here*/

}
```